# Qual è il significato di "sbandarsi" in questo contesto?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> «C’è Nadia?».
>         «No, è fuori». 
>         «Quando torna?».
>         «Mi dispiace, non lo so, tra dieci minuti, tra un’ora, fa quello che le pare». 
>         «Può dire che l’ha cercata Lina?». 
>         «È una cosa urgente?». 
>         «Sì». 
>         «Vuole dire a me?». 
>         Dire a lei cosa? Lila **si sbandò**, le venne da guardare oltre la Galiani. Si intravedeva la vecchiaia aristocratica dei mobili e dei lampadari, la libreria stracolma che l’aveva incantata, i quadri preziosi alle pareti.

Si tratta di un dialogo tra Lila (o Lina) e la professoressa Galiani. Lila è andata a casa della Galiani in cerca di Nadia, la figlia della professoresa. Il dialogo si svolge quando Lila è ancora all'uscio.

Malgrado abbia cercato il significato di "sbandarsi" in alcuni dizionari, non capisco bene il senso di questo vocabolo nel brano precedente. Sapreste spiegarmelo?

**Aggiornamento:** Adesso mi sono accorta che questo verbo appare più avanti nel libro, in questo passaggio:

> Com’erano al solito ben documentati i suoi testi, con quale logica stringente erano formulati. Sentii, come da ragazzina quando parlavo con lui, la necessità di chiudermi anch’io in una rete di proposizioni generali formulate ad arte che m’impedisse di seguitare a **sbandarmi**.

Comment: Direi che è usato in modo simile a sbaraccare. Nel senso che Lila prese e se ne andò. Però non ne sarei troppo certo.

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia: Veramente Lila non se ne va, ma finisce per entrare in casa della Galiani.

Comment: Ammetto che non lo avevo presente usato così, ma dal contesto e da questa [definizione](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sbandare2/) (2.b: «In senso fig., perdere la coesione, l’unità materiale e spirituale prima esistente all’interno di un gruppo di persone») direi che Lila perde la concentrazione, la determinazione, non sa più che dire.

Comment: In effetti, non mi sembra di averlo mai visto usato nella forma riflessiva, ma sembra proprio il verbo "sbandare" usato in modo figurato.

Comment: @DaG: E non potrebbe avere qualcosa a che vedere con muoversi lateralmente? Cioè, qualcosa a che vedere col significato spiegato in http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sbandare1/.

Comment: @Charo: Usato riflessivamente mi suona piuttosto insolito, ma potrebbe essere.

Comment: @Charo sono d'accordo con DaG, è insolito. Aggiungo che sarebbe una forzatura estrema delle possibilità del riflessivo (certamente nell'uso noi italiani lo estendiamo molto...)

Comment: Scusa, @Charo, a proposito di Lina/Lila: l'oscillazione tra i due nomi è presente in tutto il libro?

Comment: @Benedetta: Lo spiega la narratrice all'inizio del secondo capitolo del romanzo *L'amica geniale*: «La madre di Rino si chiama Raffaella Cerullo, ma tutti l’hanno sempre chiamata Lina. Io no, non ho mai usato né il primo nome né il secondo. Da più di sessant’anni per me è Lila. Se la chiamassi Lina o Raffaella, così, all’improvviso, penserebbe che la nostra amicizia è finita».

Comment: @Charo: grazie!

Comment: @DaG: Il brano che ho aggiunto sembra confermare quello che hai scritto nel tuo commento.

Comment: _Alla carica della polizia il corteo si sbandò_. _Alla sconfitta elettorale il partito si sbandò_. _Dopo la separazione la sua vita si sbandò_.  Non bellissimi ma usati e chiari.

Answer (score -1):

I due utilizzi di sbandarsi non mi sembrano collegati. Il primo (quando Lila si trova all'uscio) ritengo significhi semplicemente che si è sporta da un lato per guardare oltre la Galiani che le ostruiva la vista dell'interno della casa.

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE. This is not a forum; answers should be motivated, not simply opinions.

Comment: I am using the simple dictionary meaning of sbandare. Nothing more, nothing less. It's not an opinion.

Comment: Quale dizionario riporta “sbandarsi” col significato di “sporgersi da un lato per guardare”? Senza contare che una risposta con “mi sembrano” e “ritengo” e priva di fonti esprime chiaramente delle opinioni, non dei fatti.

Comment: Treccani riporta: "far sbandare l’imbarcazione, farla inclinare su un fianco: il forte vento sbandava la nave. 2. Per estens., di veicoli in movimento, subire uno sbandamento laterale, a sinistra o a destra". Fonte: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sbandare1/ Ovviamente per estensione il concetto si applica alla persona di Lila.

Comment: Non mi sembra tanto ovvio. Lo sbandamento è causato da forze esterne; sporgersi di lato è un'azione volontaria. Pregherei di adoperare un linguaggio più cauto.

Comment: Concordo con @egreg: non diremmo per esempio che una persona “deraglia” o “derapa” per dire che si sporge (al limite per dire che cade in malo modo, ma anche lì sarebbe forzato).

Comment: Giusta osservazione ma notate il peculiare uso del riflessivo che serve proprio a rimuovere l'idea di agente esterno all'opera.